# How to bulk insert in Oracle

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I have to load bulk amount of data from one DB instance to other DB instance,The requirement is to use DBlinks only.

Using SQLLDR i am able to achieve speed of 200K records per sec , and wish to replicate the same using DBLinks.

Insert with direct path(append hint) gives me max of 40k records per sec.
But since insert with direct path aquires table level , i cannot open multiple sessions to scale it up to 200K.

Since the Conventional inserts are very slow and i might have to open 30 to 40 sessions to meet the required speed.Is there a way to achieve parallel direct path inserts in to the same table?Or is there any other way or DB tuning  which can help me increase the inserts per sec?

Note : I have already tried partitioned table and the lock is still on table and not on partition.

Comment: Loading to the remote db directly is advisable. So you can download the data into a file, and use the data file to DIRECT load into the other db. USing PARALLEL enable you to speed up the process by opening up multiple sessions of SQL loader.

Comment: Can you use the datapump API over your DB link?

Comment: depending on the total size of the data to be transfered, the performance my actually be comparable when you factor in the time taken to unload the data in source database, serialize to disk, transfer the file over network etcetera.

Comment: I tried increasing degree of parallelism , but there wasnt much benefit in the throughput.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution by using insert append with partition clause.
If the insert clause contains partition information then the lock is on the partition and not on the table.

Wrote the query like:

Insert /*+ append */  into destination partition(ptnName) select * from source@dblink where (partition filtering condition).

I created 8 partition in the target table and started 8 session for loading in to respective partitions.It got me the performance which matches the speed of SQLLDR.